# Meaning of the word "how" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> Too much of anything can kill you, water included.  **How** is this plasma in the blood and decreases the amount of sodium (salt).

It doesn't seem to be a question. I am puzzled. Is there some kind of typo in the sentence. If not, explain the last sentence and the grammar to me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a typo. If you read carefully, you will see that the next sentence also does not make sense. (I simply [googled](https://books.google.nl/books?id=i1haDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%22Too+much+of+anything+can+kill+you,+water+included.+How+is+this+plasma+in+the+blood+and+decreases+the+amount+of+sodium%22&source=bl&ots=Q9MyQh83Ap&sig=ACfU3U32Irq_K_STpZ_b-wiN0LD6cB4DHw&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb9Yago6ngAhVSZ1AKHbI4DfEQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Too%20much%20of%20anything%20can%20kill%20you%2C%20water%20included.%20How%20is%20this%20plasma%20in%20the%20blood%20and%20decreases%20the%20amount%20of%20sodium%22&f=false) your exact quote). There, an extraneous 'possible?' is present. Obviously, the sentence is supposed to be "How is this possible?", followed by the popular scientific explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense at all, and I can't see any obvious typo.

My reading is that the writer started a question "How is this ... ?", and accidentally deleted the rest of this, and the start of the next sentence.